Error in Github actions - Unable to find image 'docker-repository:latest' locally
Facing error "Unable to find image 'docker-repository:latest' locally" in Github action while docker run.
  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      .
      .
      .

      - name: Run Docker Container
        run: sudo docker run -d -p 3002:3002 --name ${{ env.DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME }} ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}



I explored and found the solutions, I need to add the TAG_NAME in the docker run command.
Here is the solution:
Provide the tag name while the docker run. Use the below command in GitHub actions:
sudo docker run -d -p 3002:3002 --name ${{ env.DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME }} ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}:${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG_NAME }}
ADD_YOUR_TAG_NAME should be there.
Here are the correct codes:
  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      .
      .
      .

      - name: Run Docker Container
        run: sudo docker run -d -p 3002:3002 --name ${{ env.DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME }} ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL }}:${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG_NAME }}

Once you update this, you will not get this error.


FYI, in a run step, you can replace ${{ env.VARNAME }} with $VARNAME
